# Defining a lambda to search a vector of pointers to custom Type

Tags: c++, vector, stl, lambda

I want to search a vector consisting of pointer to custom type according to an attribute. But I don't figure out how to define the lambda properly. Here is my code.

```
template<typename T>
class State {
public:
  unsigned int id;
  ...
};
```

And another class holding a vector of State pointers:

```
class System {
public:
  std::vector<State<type>*> list_;
  State<type>* getState(unsigned int id) {
    auto it = find_if(list_.begin(), list_.end(), [id](const State<type>* st&) {st->id == id;});
    if (it == list_.end()) 
      return nullptr;
    return *it;
  }
 ...
};
```

But I mix up using references and pointers in the lambda defintion. Whats the correct way to check whether `list_` contains a `state` with a specific `id`?

Thanks for help!

Regards

Comment: It might help if you actually return a value from your lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, the ampersand should be before the parameter name: `const State<type>*& st`. That declares `st` to be a reference to a pointer to a constant `State<type>`.

You also have to actually *return* something from the lambda.

Other than that it looks okay, though I recommend you to either not use pointers (they are often not needed) or at least use smart pointers like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: works, changed find call to `auto it = find_if(list_.begin(), list_.end(), [id](const State<type>*& st) {return (st->id == id);});`